# Transform timestamp string in UNIQUE integer

Tags: java, database, type-conversion, primary-key, unique

I have to transform an a timestamp string like: `20140912125314001 (yyyymmddhhMMssSSS)` in a generic **unique Integer** value that i can use like PK (PK field in my database is Number(9)).

How can i do?

Comment: Is timestamps unique?

Comment: you might want to take a long on this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997514/how-to-convert-datetime-to-a-number-with-a-precision-greater-than-days-in-t-sql

Comment: @Alboz no, in int. Because the lenght of PK in the database is max 9 digits.

Comment: @Zany than you can't. Try to execute System.currentTimeMillis() and see how many digits you get...

Comment: @talex not always, i have multiple sub-systems that can send at my concentrator various informations at same time

Comment: @Alboz is a long System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: @Zany there is only one way you can do it. Use autincrement PK

Comment: @Zany Of course because the actual time doesn't fit in an int. It means that you can't convert timestamp into an int.

Comment: @talex i know, but i post the question because i prefer to follow another solution

Comment: @Zany there is no other solution. It is impossible to convert non unique data to unique.

Comment: @Zany it's how math works. You cannot assign any possible long to a unique int. It's just impossible.

Comment: something like: "sum or weight sum of each timestamp digit?" is impossibile too? can't we prove the uniqueness?

Comment: If you can afford to keep a state, you could adapt a logic based on the maximum records per time period. Say, if you know that you will absolutely never have more than 100 record within the same minute, then your ID = (number of minutes since some predefined timestamp in the past, say 1/1/2010)*100 + (record number within current minute). This example would hit the 9 digit limit around the end of 2028 :).

Answer (score 0):

Since you still have not got a full answer I'd summarize what was already written here as comments.

Your question can be separated into 3 sub-questions

1. How to parse date `20140912125314001` formatted using format `yyyymmddhhMMssSSS`.
2. How to put the result into `int` type
3. How to use the resulting `int` as a primary key in database.

The answer to the first question is: use `SimpleDateFormat`. You will get `Date`, then invoke `getTime()` to get milliseconds.

The answer to the second question has been already done: you cannot put `long` into `int` without loosing your data.

However I can suggest you a workaround: you probably do not need milliseconds since January, 1, 1970. I guess that it is enough to get milliseconds from the beginning of your application installation. For example you can get the timestamp when you install the application and then subtract this number from current timestamp, so you will get reasonable number that hopefully will not exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

The third part is using the timestamp as a primary key in relational database. I am sorry, but this is completely wrong. Computers work fast. Millisecond is not too much. Computers can perform thousands of operation during one millisecond. This actually means that you should never use timestamp as a primary key or even field with unique constraint. If you want to relate your primary key to time you can use `UUID` instead. However (as it was already mentioned) relational databases provide you much better tool: automatically incremented sequence. Use it as a primary key and if you want store timestamp (either in seconds, milliseconds or in any other format) as an additional field that can be used for queries.